# what is the requirement of oc_category_path table exists in opencart?

Tags: path, opencart, categories

I am unable to understand the concept of having category_path table in opencart. Can any opencart expert here explain with a scenario/example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `category_path` table stores data relating to the category hierarchy.  For instance, suppose you have top level category "Shoes" with category_id 7.  "Shoes" has a sub category called "Gators" with category_id 11.  In the admin panel you would see something like:

```
Shoes > Gators
```

The `category_path` table would have rows like:

```
+-------------+---------+-------+
| category_id | path_id | level |
+-------------+---------+-------+
|          11 |       7 |     0 |
|          11 |      11 |     1 |
+-------------+---------+-------+
```

The row where the path_id is equal to the category_id tells you how many levels deep the category is.  The other rows show it's parents and their respective level.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. You seems to have a great hands on opencart. :) I would like to ask more questions to you.

Comment: Since `category` table itself stores the category's `parent_id`, and the hierarchy may be computed, it seems to be that `category_path` table's purpose is the performance optimization. This pattern is called Closure Table, and it allows fetching mentioned hierarchical structure in a single SQL query instead of running several queries in a loop or using a massive query with joins.